# Variable not interprate inside loop shell script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, file, sh

I tried to made a save inside a SSH connection from files inside a folder with a script, I don't understand why but

```
  expect \"ssh>\"
    send \"for ENTRY in "pathtomyfolder"/*; do cp /DOMP/appli/bin/$(basename $ENTRY) /pathtofolder/$(basename $ENTRY).somedate; done \r\"
```

But it seems that my variable isn't interprate inside my script, it's empty. If I launched the loop from the SSH connection it works fine it's juste inside the script that it doesn't work. If you could help me thank you.

Edit : Thank for you replies sorry for my lack of informations, I've made a minimal reproductible example :

```
#!/bin/sh

HORODATAGE=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
for entry in "folder"/*
do
  cp "\$entry" "\$entry.$HORODATAGE"
done
```

I've tried to escape my variable but it doesn't work too...

Comment: This isn't just a `sh` script, it's a `sh` script embedded inside an `expect` script -- that's an extra level of complexity. I'd strongly, _strongly_ urge you to figure out whether you have a `sh` problem or an `expect` problem and ask about one or the other, but not both at the same time.

Comment: (if `expect` is munging your values before they get to the remote `sh`, that's not a problem that someone who's a `sh` expert can be expected to know about and help you with; `expect` is a completely different programming language from an entirely unrelated family).

Comment: Also, it's possible (maybe even likely!) that you're passing code into `expect` via an unquoted heredoc; but if that's the case (and it would explain your problem), you simply aren't providing enough details to diagnose it here, since you aren't showing us how you _start_ `expect`.

Comment: ...consider trying to build a [mre] -- the shortest possible self-contained code someone can use to see the problem themselves, when running it on their own machine. (Obviously, someone's "own machine" won't have a `/DOMP/appli/bin` directory; but you can just do something like ssh into a machine and `for entry in "$HOME"/*; do echo "Found in your home directory: $entry"; done` or such as an example that'll work for more people).

Comment: ...to be clear what I mean about an "unquoted heredoc" -- if this code is inside something like `expect <<EOF`, then from there until the `EOF`, any parameter expansion -- like `$ENTRY` -- will be replaced with the current value of the `ENTRY` variable __at the time the heredoc is evaluated__, so before the `for ENTRY in` loop is ever started. That can be fixed by changing the `<<EOF` to `<<'EOF'` to turn off such interpretation entirely; or adding a backslash before the `$` in `$ENTRY`.

Comment: (By the way -- all-caps variable names are in reserved space; you should use names with at least one lower-case character for your own variables -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that both environment variables and regular shell variables share a namespace: Setting the latter will overwrite the former if their names overlap).

Answer (score 0):

By escaping the variables, you basically told the shell "please do not expand it". Hence, you should have written it as

```
#!/bin/sh
HORODATAGE=`date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`
for entry in "folder"/*
do
  cp "$entry" "$entry.$HORODATAGE"
done
```

BTW, I would write the assignment of the date as

```
HORODATAGE=$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

but of course, your approach is not wrong either.